# Relations between iterate Kleisli-EM-construction relative a distributive law of monads

Tags: ct.category-theory

Given two monads $(T, \mu, \eta),\ (S, \mu', \eta')$ on a category $\mathcal{C}$, and a distributive law $\lambda: TS\to ST$.
I indicate with  $\mathcal{C}^T$ the Eilenberg-Moore category of $T$-algebras, and with  $\mathcal{C}_S$ the Kleisli-category of  $S$. We have:

1. A monad morphism  $(S, \lambda): (T, \mu, \eta)\to (T, \mu, \eta)$ this is a monad in the monad 2-category i.e.
   $\mu': (S, \lambda)\circ (S, \lambda)\to (S, \lambda),\ \eta': 1\to (S, \lambda)$ are 2-cell in the monad 2-category.

We have  a functor  $\hat{S}: \mathcal{C}^T\to \mathcal{C}^T$ on object $\hat{S}(x, X)= (S(x)\circ \lambda_X, X)$ $x: T(X)\to X$ a $T$-algebra, with $S\circ U^T= U^T\circ \hat{S}$ where $U^T: \mathcal{C}^T\to \mathcal{C}$ canonical,  $\hat{S}$ is a part of a monad inducted by $(S, \mu', \eta')$.

2. A monad op.morphism  $(T, \lambda): (S, \mu', \eta')\to (S, \mu', \eta')$ this is a monad in the monad (with op.morphisms) 2-category i.e.
   $\mu: (T, \lambda)\circ (T, \lambda)\to (T, \lambda),\ \eta: 1\to (T, \lambda)$ are 2-cells in the monad (with op.morphisms) 2-category.

We have  a functor  $\bar{T}: \mathcal{C}_S\to \mathcal{C}_S$ on object $\bar{T}(X)= T(X)$ on morphisms $\bar{T}: (f)_{X, Y}\mapsto 
( \lambda_Y\circ  Tf)_{TX, TY}$, $\bar{T}$ is a part of a monad inducted by $(T, \mu, \eta)$.

3. A monad $ST$ on $\mathcal{C}$, with composition  $STST\xrightarrow{S\lambda T}SSTT\xrightarrow{\mu\circ \mu }ST$ with identity $\eta'_T\ast \eta=S\eta\ast\eta'$.

Then we have the categories $(\mathcal{C}^T)_{\hat{S}},\ (\mathcal{C}_S)^{\bar{T}},\ (\mathcal{C}^{T})^{\hat{S}},\ \mathcal{C}^{ST}$ .

***How are they  related in some way***?

References:

Ross Street: The formal theory of monads.

Saunders MacLane : Categories for the Working Mathematician

Comment: To clarify: when you ask "How are they related in some way?", does "they" refer to the categories $(\mathcal{C}^T)_{\hat{S}},\ (\mathcal{C}_S)^{\bar{T}},\ (\mathcal{C}^{T})^{\hat{S}},\ \mathcal{C}^{ST}$? For instance -- I haven't thought about this carefully, but I imagine that at least some of these categories are equivalent to each other -- is that the sort of thing you're after?

Comment: Your profile says that you have studied some category theory and like it but are not an academic researcher.  With this kind of question it's more fun to investigate it for yourself than read someone else's solution.  Get a **large** piece of paper, draw out all the diagrams that express the data and see what you can construct or deduce.  Hint: with monads, you should assume that in the underlying category any idempotent splits into an epi and a mono.

Comment: May be are related by some lax-pullback realtion I dont know.

For Paul Taylor, is just what I did, but sometime I find a (for me) hard  problem.